# Is it a vulnerability to create a nonce and output it as a data-attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a list of static items on a WordPress site and when a user hovers over each item, the site loads new data elsewhere using Ajax + querying the WordPress database via PHP.

In the list, I have made each item have its own created nonce (using wp_create_nonce() )as an attribute, and other relevant dynamic bits of data needed (such as category id) so the final HTML looks something like this:

```
<li data-nonce="abc" data-category-id="1">Option A</li>
<li data-nonce="def" data-category-id="2">Option B</li>
<li data-nonce="ghi" data-category-id="3">Option C</li>
```

Then in Javascript, I do something like this (shortened of course):

```
on li hover {
var nonce = hoveredLi.attr('data-nonce'),
    catid = hoveredLi.attr('data-category-id');
$.ajax({ type : "GET", data : { action: 'the_function', nonce: nonce, catid: catid }.....
```

Then in PHP I start the ajax function by confirming the nonce:

```
function the_function() {

  if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['nonce'], 'nonce' ) ) {
    die();
  }

  $cat_id = isset( $_GET['catid '] ) && $_GET['catid '] ?  intval($_GET['catid '] ) : 0;
  $qry = new WP_Query( 'cat' => $cat_id, );
  // rest of function ....
}
```

Is that the correct way to try to make the ajax call safe? Or is have the nonce so easily visible (data-none attribute) need to be changed?

If a hacker tried to alter the data in the nonce using developer tools, would it always fail?

If a hacker tried to inject malicious code via the category ID attribute, is using Intval the best way to try to sanitize the category id? Categories are always integers, so would that be the most effective way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [WordPress nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) is just for protecting against [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29). Someone could modify the nonce using any number of methods (hiding it would be pointless), but a nonce is user-specific, so they would just invalidate it.

Just make sure you also verify that the user has the appropriate permissions to perform the action in the AJAX handler, in addition to verifying the nonce to ensure that the user actually performed the action. A nonce does not validate that a user has permissions to perform an action, just that the user intentionally performed it.

For example, if your AJAX handler allows a user to edit a post, you would want to do something like this.

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['nonce'], 'nonce' ) ) {
    die();
}
```

As for your other question, sure, cast it to an integer using either `intval` or `(int)`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "verify appropriate permissions"? Because the list is visible on the front-end side of the website (anyone who visits the site can see it), wouldn't that mean technically "everyone" should have permission to perform the action?

Comment: Is CORF an acronym for "cross-origin …" or a typo of CSRF?

Comment: @Bergi That would be a typo

Comment: @balecap I'll add an example of validating permissions, but if everyone should have access, why the nonce?

Comment: Thanks again, and I just assumed that because the ajax calls a PHP function that queries the database, it had to use a nonce in the function. Which would lead to the question, when do you need a nonce then, if you can simply validate by user permissions and intval for integers, etc?

Comment: @balecap I linked to the Owasp CSRF page, which I would highly recommend reading, but in short, imagine in directed you to a page with an image tag like this `<img src="http://yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=delete_post&post=123" />`. It would create a network request using your session to trigger the `delete_post` action if it exists, and pass `123` and the `post` parameter. However, if it requires a nonce, I would have no idea what the value of the nonce would need to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely expose nonces in your code, every user gets different nonces (excellent explanation [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141839)). A nonce is always salted making it "infeasible to duplicate the nonce" for hackers. `intval` will sanitize the cat input effectively.

Answer (score 0):

In both your scenario and the "[recommended practice](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)" scenario, the DOM can theoretically be modified by the end user to represent a nonce that was not allocated to them.  (And Wordpress checks for the user assigned.)  Measured risk.

However, what you're doing is no different from the recommended practice of adding the nonce to a hidden field.  It's visible if the users can view the current HTML of the page either way, so I'd say you're safe.